# How to get data with $.ajax() jquery and display to the HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need help in retrieving data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/',
  data: { userId: 1 },
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {   
    $("#posts").html("<p><h3>" + data[0].title + "</h3></p>");
    console.log(data);
    $("#posts").append("<p>" + data[0].body + "</p>");
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

How can I set the `data: userId` to not only 1 but a range of values like 1 to 5 or 1 to 10? And how do I append all of them by displaying in my html file?

Comment: use `success` function. jQuery will call it with param `data`

Comment: Also the site is not important here in SO

Comment: @SagarV OP does have a success callback in there

Comment: @SagarV OP is already doing that. Hopefully the code is a bit clearer now I edited in some indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple click way

### HTML:

```
<div data-action="getUsers" data-users="1,2,3,4,5">Get Users</div>
```

### JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-action=getUsers]").on("click", function(){
        // get userId someway
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data();
        var users_string = data.users;
        var userIds_str_array = users_string.spilt(","); // this will turn a string into an array of strings split by given char
        var userIds_int_array = [];
        var length = (userIds_str_array.length - 1);
        // convert to ints, might be overkill, strings might be fine, this is your call
        for(let i = length; i--;){ // short hand for-loop, use if order doesnt matter
            let value = userIds_str_array[i];
            let test_val = parseInt(value);
            // short hand if
            // return true to skip iteration
            isNaN(test_val) === false ? userIds_int_array.push(value) : return true;
        }
        // make sure you are not wasting your time.
        if(userIds_int_array.length > 1){
            return GetUserFromPosts(user, function(responce){
                if(responce.users){
                    if(responce.users.length > 0){
                        // func call
                        return doSomethingWithUsers(responce.users);
                    }else{
                        return false; // no users in array
                    }
                }else{
                    return false; // there was probably a 500 error
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return false // no users in array
        }
    })
})

function GetUserFromPosts(userId_arr, callback){
    var data = {userId: userId_arr}; // I assume your api can accept an array, if not, you have to do seperate calls for each one. 
    $.ajax({
        url: root + '/posts/',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {   
            console.log(data);
            return callback(data);
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I get your point, but what if I want the `userId` to not only be a certain value but multiple values? How do I also append all of those multiple `userId` 's title and body to the html webpage. Like do I use for loop?

Comment: Have you figured this out? It was two days ago. I'll update my comment on a moment.

Comment: I changed the click function to split a string of IDs into an array. I assume the function call will accept an array. If not, use a promise and a generator to get each value in the array. And then have it return when all the values have been retrieved. see http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_generators.html